# Which manga chapter should I start to continue from season 3 of My Hero Academia?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Season 3 of *My Hero Academia* has ended, and I'm curious about the continuation in the manga.

Which chapter should I start to continue from season 3?

Answer (score 3):

From [MangaUpdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=112459), **Season 3** ends at **Vol. 14 Chapter 124** of the manga.